# Construct a meaningful phrase

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern

- If (4, 3, 15) means "I am Liam", then 14 is a feminine name.
- If (15, 3, 7) means "This is his", then 6 is a way of greeting someone.

---

***Construct a meaningful phrase for (8, 7, 9) when 15 becomes the name of a country.***

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A suitable phrase would be:

> **I ran in**, where the country is **Iran**.

Why? Because:

> The number 15 in binary is 1111. All numbers less than 15 will comprise a combination of up to four 0's and 1's. If the number 15 maps to the full 4-letter word given in each example, then the other numbers hint at the other corresponding words, based on which letters map to the 1's present in the number's binary representation.
>
>  If that's a bit tricky to wrap your head around, here's a practical run-through:
>
>  (4, 3, 15) = "I am Liam":
>  15 = 1111 = LIAM
>  4 = 0100 = -I--
>  3 = 0011 = --AM
>  and 14 = 1110 = LIA- (a feminine name)
>
>  (15, 3, 7) = "This is his":
>  15 = 1111 = THIS
>  3 = 0011 = --IS
>  7 = 0111 = -HIS
>  and 6 = 0110 = -HI- (a way of greeting someone)

So, for my chosen example:

> If 15 = 1111 = IRAN:
>  8 = 1000 = I---
>  7 = 0111 = -RAN
>  9 = 1001 = I--N
>
>  Hence (8,7,9) = **I ran in**.

Comment: Nice, just add "LIA" and "HI" for the 1st and 2nd clue respectively.

Comment: @z100 Oops, yes, I meant to do that! Thanks for the prod...